# Using the background worker with openfiledialog list

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is in my application, i'm loading in a list of URLs via a .txt file, passing each line of the .txt file in to the backgroundworker to be processed, breaking the thread to update the UI, i'm getting the error:

**'This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.'**

**Code:**

```cs
private void BtnImportURLs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
        Title = "Select URLs file ...",
        DefaultExt = "txt",
        Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
        FilterIndex = 2,
    };

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
        {
            if (bgWorker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                var line = string.Empty;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(line.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

public void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        Helpers.ReturnMessage(string.Format("Thread error: {0}", e.Error));
    else if (e.Cancelled)
        Helpers.ReturnMessage("The process was cancelled.");
    else
        Helpers.ReturnMessage("URLs have been imported successfully.");
}

private void BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var input_url = e.Argument as string;
    var platform = string.Empty;

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { platform = comboBoxSelectMassMacroTemplate.Text; }));

    if (platform == "platform-[buddypress].txt")
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            string root_domain = Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url);
            if (!File.Exists(@"Macros\MassMacros\" + root_domain + ".txt"))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"Macros\" + Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url) + ".txt", txtBoxPlatformMassMacro.Text.Replace("%DOMAIN%", Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url)));
                txtBoxMassMacroOutput.AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now}] - " + Helpers.GetBuddyPressFlags(input_url) + " - " + Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url));
                txtBoxMassMacroOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

I know looking over the code it's because i'm passing the line to be processed each time it's read, is this the proper way to go about what i'm trying to do? i feel i have some code where i shouldn't, like, should i have the while loop in the backgroundworker too? i'm a bit of a noob with backgroundworkers, appreciate any help.

Comment: Just pass the filename to the BackgroundWorker.DoWork and let it open and loop over the file

Comment: Why dont you use Async Tasks and await for Result, I,ve been start  using this last month and i am really impressed from it. Search for **Async Task handling and await** , i be it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Steve, i never even thought, @Sayed that is next on my list :) i heard Async was a lot better than the BG thank you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the `RunWorkerAsync()` call is asynchronous and you're not waiting for it to complete:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(line.ToString());
}
```

You need to explicitly tell your loop to wait for the worker to finish before processing a new URL. Something like this will probably work (not tested):

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(line.ToString());
    //Keep looping til the worker is finished.
    while(bgWorker.IsBusy) 
        Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

As others have said, I would personally use the `async`/`await` pattern to accomplish what you want. Something like this would likely work (again, I haven't tested this):

```
private async void BtnImportURLs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
        Title = "Select URLs file ...",
        DefaultExt = "txt",
        Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
        FilterIndex = 2,
    };

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach(string s in File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName))
        {
            await ProcessUrl(s, comboBoxSelectMassMacroTemplate.Text);
        }
    }
}

private async Task ProcessUrl(string Url, string SelectedMassMacroTemplate)
{
    var input_url = Url;
    var platform = SelectedMassMacroTemplate;

    if (platform == "platform-[buddypress].txt")
    {
        string root_domain = Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url);
        if (!File.Exists(@"Macros\MassMacros\" + root_domain + ".txt"))
        {
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync(@"Macros\" + Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url) + ".txt", txtBoxPlatformMassMacro.Text.Replace("%DOMAIN%", Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url)));
            txtBoxMassMacroOutput.AppendText($"[{DateTime.Now}] - " + Helpers.GetBuddyPressFlags(input_url) + " - " + Helpers.GetRootUrl(input_url));
            txtBoxMassMacroOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Using `async`/`await`, you don't need to `Invoke` to update the UI so long as your code does not run in a separate thread.

EDIT: The `File.WriteAllTextAsync()` method appears to only be available in the .Net Standard 2.1 Preview. You may need to [implement a file stream and write all the lines asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774827/writing-to-a-file-asynchronously#22617832), or run the write operation in a separate thread using `Task.Run()` (may be less efficient).

Comment: wow Thank you Patrick, that is a much better way, i will learn to use Async / Await in future.